# How do I instantiate a UITabBarController programmatically from a storyboard?

Tags: swift

I have a storyboard that includes a TabBarController Scene. I'm trying to instantiate it programmatically and then set it as the rootViewController.

I have put a breakpoint after setting the storyboard variable and can confirm that it finds it. The problem is happening loading the scene for the TabBarController.

I have tried creating a custom TabBarController subclass and setting that as the "Class" name in identity inspector and I get the same thing.

I have also tried instantiating UIViewControllers in the same storyboard and they open up fine. It's just happening with the TabBarController. Maybe this is a limitation and cannot be done.

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryboardConstants.Composition, bundle: nil)
        if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tabbar") as? UITabBarController {
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load the scene view controller for identifier 'Tabbar''
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 6):

[image: Storyboard reference without name]

Finally got it to work! So I had everything set correctly in the identity inspector, the problem was that I did not assign a Storyboard to the Storyboard reference that I have linked to the TabBarController.

The error did not give me a clue but hopefully, this will help someone.

Comment: How do you assign a Storyboard to the Storyboard reference?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the storyboard ID for this view controller.

1. Open the storyboard.
2. Select the yellow ViewController
3. Tap the identity inspector (3rd tap in the group on the right)
4. Enter "Tabbar" in the "Storyboard ID" field

Comment: [Link](https://prntscr.com/n4qwye)  I did enter the storyboard id, here's a screenshot of what I have.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add tabbar to project target. One other option is to clean your project and rebuild and check from identity inspector if there is a disconnected connection from storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot that explains what "check from identity inspector if there is a disconnected connection from storyboard" looks like?